# Filter an array within another array using projection in mongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am doing the aggregation operation with MongoDB and have done the lookup etc to get the documents in the following way.

```
[
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("6407e265a15acdb137ec651e"),
        "myLocalId": "id1c1",
        "title": "id1c1 title",
        "details": [
            {
                "myLocalId": "id1e2",
                "title": "id2e2 title2",
                "subarray": [
                    {
                        "_id": "id1c1",
                        "displayName": "id1c1 for id2e2"
                      
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "id1c2",
                        "displayName": "id1c2 for id2e2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "myLocalId": "id2e3",
                "title": "id2e3 title3",
                "subarray": [
                    {
                        "_id": "id1c1",
                        "displayName": "id1c1 for id2e3"
                      
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "id2c2",
                        "displayName": "id2c2 for id2e3"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("6407e26da15acdb137ec651f"),
        "myLocalId": "id2c2",
        "title": "id2c2 title",
        "details": [
            {
                "_id": ObjectId("6407e385a15acdb137ec6526"),
                "myLocalId": "id2e1",
                "title": "id2e1 title",
                "subarray": [
                    {
                        "_id": "id2c2",
                        "displayName": "id2c2 for id2e1"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "id2c3",
                        "displayName": "id2c3 for id2e1"
                    }
                    
                ]
            },
            {
                "_id": ObjectId("6407e385a15acdb137ec6526"),
                "myLocalId": "id2e2",
                "title": "id2e1 title",
                "subarray": [
                    {
                        "_id": "id2c2",
                        "displayName": "id2c2 for id2e2"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "id2c4",
                        "displayName": "id2c4 for id2e2"
                    }
                    
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
  
]
```

I now need to filter out the subarray where the _id matches the parent myLocalId. I am using the project operator to select only the fields I need as the next stage for lookup and then doing the filter to remove the unnecessary sub-elements. However, when I do the filter on sub array things are not working as expected.
The output what I am trying to generate is something like this

```
[
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("6407e265a15acdb137ec651e"),
        "myLocalId": "id1c1",
        "title": "id1c1 title",
        "details": [
            {
                "myLocalId": "id1e2",
                "title": "id2e2 title2",
                "subarray": [
                    {
                        "_id": "id1c1",
                        "displayName": "id1c1 for id2e2"
                      
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "myLocalId": "id2e3",
                "title": "id2e3 title3",
                "subarray": [
                    {
                        "_id": "id1c1",
                        "displayName": "id1c1 for id2e3"
                      
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("6407e26da15acdb137ec651f"),
        "myLocalId": "id2c2",
        "title": "id2c2 title",
        "details": [
            {
                "_id": ObjectId("6407e385a15acdb137ec6526"),
                "myLocalId": "id2e1",
                "title": "id2e1 title",
                "subarray": [
                    {
                        "_id": "id2c2",
                        "displayName": "id2c2 for id2e1"
                    }
                    
                ]
            },
            {
                "_id": ObjectId("6407e385a15acdb137ec6526"),
                "myLocalId": "id2e2",
                "title": "id2e1 title",
                "subarray": [
                    {
                        "_id": "id2c2",
                        "displayName": "id2c2 for id2e2"
                    }
                    
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
  
]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this https://mongoplayground.net/p/r3HvN-W6O3d

where we have below aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$details"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$details.subarray"
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "myLocalIdMatched": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            $eq: [
              "$myLocalId",
              "$details.subarray._id"
            ]
          },
          "then": true,
          "else": false
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      myLocalIdMatched: true
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "myLocalId": {
        "$first": "$myLocalId"
      },
      "title": {
        "$first": "$title"
      },
      "details": {
        "$addToSet": "$details"
      },
      
    }
  }
])
```

here we have unwinded details and subarray and then compared the myLocalId with details.subarray .id and collected matched elements and grouped them again... pls note this is sample solutionand it will not work for all cases you might need to do grouping at subarray level first then do again grouping at details level to ensure data accuracy as we are doing unwinding twice!